# Star Rating Bootstrap Data Input to Flask

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, flask

After much help and many attempts at getting this functional I have now done so. The code below should be sufficient should anyone else also want to do the same.

Jinja2 Template

```
<div class="panel-footer">
  <label for="input-2" class="control-label">My Rating:</label>
<input id="stars_{{result.id}}" name="input-2" class="rating rating-loading" data-min="0" data-max="10" data-step="0.1" data-stars="10" data-size="xs"onchange="updateStars('{{result.id}}')" >
</div>
   <form action="{{url_for('delete_f', id=result.id)}}" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger">
      </form>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
    {% for result in results %}
<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateStars(id) {
       var rating = document.getElementById("stars_" + id).value;
       $.ajax({
           url : '/rate_movie',
           headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
           type : 'POST',
           dataType: 'json',
           data : JSON.stringify{'id': 'id', 'rating': rating}
           });
};
</script>
{% endfor %}
```

Flask Backend

```
@app.route('/rate_movie',methods=['GET','POST'])
def rate_movie():

    # Create cursor
if request.method == 'POST':

    data = request.get_json(force=True)
    rating = data['rating']
    id = data['id'] 
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
        # Execute
    #cursor.execute("UPDATE favourites SET rating=5  WHERE id =49") ## Works 
    cursor.execute("UPDATE favourites SET rating=%s  WHERE id =%s",(rating,id))
    #("INSERT INTO favourites(rating)VALUES(%s) WHERE id =%s" ,(rating,id))
        # Commit to DB
    cnx.commit()

        #Close connection
    cursor.close()

    flash('Movie Rated', 'success')
return redirect(url_for('my_f'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of problems here, but your first big issue is that you're using non-unique ids.  Make your Ids unique and you can properly reference the value of your hidden input, fix your jQuery listener to look like `$('#actually_uniqe_id').on('change', function (){...}` instead of the mess it is currently, you can get your value correctly with `var rating = document.getElementById("#actually_unique_id").value;` and modify your posted data to convey both the id and rating like `data: {'id': {{result.id}}, 'rating': rating}`.

Never use non-unique IDs.  Because of confusion surrounding this point, your current jQuery event listener is meaningless, and your rate_id variable is undefined because `document.getElementById("{{result.id}}")` fetches the first reference of that id, which is a div that has no attribute 'value'.

Edit: Also, since you have a loop generating potentially lots of rating inputs, drop the event listener for something like:

```
<input id="value_{{result.id}}" type="hidden" onchange="updateStars('{{result.id}}')" />
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateStars(id) {
       var rating = document.getElementById("value_" + id).value;
       $.ajax({
           url : '/dashboard',
           type : 'POST',
           data : {'id': '{{result.id}}', 'rating': rating}
       });
</script>
```

Comment: by 'actually unique' Can I essentially change the current div to anything unique, or does every instance of the div have to be unique ?

Comment: @BobSingh Every id, whether on a div or an input, must be unique.  You can't have '<input id="{{result.id}}.../>' twice and yes, if you have multiple instances of '<div id="{{result.id}}"...>' that's also a problem.  A class can be shared, but ids must be unique or you'll run into a lot of problems like the one you're experiencing now, where getElementById doesn't return the expected node.

Comment: The way you have it, each result in your loop has a different result.id, but reusing that as HTML ids within each iteration is a big problem. You could add some variation by simply changing the two input ids to something like id="stars_{{result.id}}" and id="value_{{result.id}}". Also, since you have a loop, better than an event listener, add onclick= "updateStars({{result.id}})" to each input and create a single updateStars() function to handle it.  I've edited my answer to clarify.

Comment: I really appreciate all the help you've given and have made changes above to reflect your input. I am still struggling to save user rated input to the back-end.

Comment: Can you post some errors?  Check the browser JS console when you try to click to add a rating first, and post any error output here.  you may also try adding some console.log() for different variables in a few places.  If the JS console looks fine, try the flask error log.

Comment: It occured to me that I'm not familiar with the bootstrap star ratings.  If the hidden field isn't updating its value when you change the star ratings, then you will need to set the onchange on the other input, `stars_{{result.id}}`

Comment: Your comments are spot on, I can now see the post occurring, however I now keep getting 404 not found, when attempting to post.

Comment: Make sure '/dashboard' is right.  If you list the flask route as '/dashboard/' with the trailing slash, it won't match.

Comment: I've tried both '/rate_movie' and '/rate_movie/'. Both return a 404 error

Comment: Last place to check is the flask error log.  If youve deployed the application with apache thats the apache error logs.  If youve deployed it on the flask test server with debug set to true then you can access the in browser interactive debug.  Try navigating directly to the route and see what errors it throws.  404 with routes ok is most likely a syntax error, flask not running, or trying to access the route with a prohibited method (ie. trying to post when you only allow get)

Comment: The issue looks like it is arising from the flask element, i removed the <string:id> part, the error is now a 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Ok, you added the flask backend after my first comments i think.  If you drop the id part, then everywhere that references the id variable is referencing an undefined variable.  It looks like your MySQL was the problem.  Your using insert when you want update favorites set rating = %s where id = %s if the data for those fields is interger, else turn each %s into '%s'. From there on, you should be able to debug any remaining errors.  If you have trouble, copy some error log info here.

Comment: I'm not too certain on where to find the log info, I have tried a few different things, strangely I can post to a different @route, but when I try adding the request.get, I get another 5000 error.

Comment: If the app is deployed with apache, its in your system's apache error log.  If its the test server deployed from cli, you should see errors on the console.

Comment: I've attached the logs and the error above, 'NoneType' is not subscriptable

Comment: @BobSingh There's really only so much that I can do without us going back and forth on every error, but I'm happy to provide guidance to help someone else get started with Flask.  It's a great framework.  What I can do that is best from here is give you a few pointers on how to effectively troubleshoot your code.  Try it, when it fails, hit the logs and see what the error is and what line threw it, then go to that line and see what object is problematic and trace it back to the source to find out why.  Then reload/restart and try again.

Comment: @BobSingh In this case it looks like you're trying to access something inside of an object you expect to be a container (list, tuple, etc), but the object has been defined as None.

Comment: I have managed to address a few more of the errors that have come up, I hope/ think this is the last one, which is an SQL error. on Line  cursor.execute("INSERT INTO favourites(rating)VALUES(%s) WHERE id =%s" ,(rating,id)). I don't think you can have an insert into where statement

Comment: Great!  I'm glad to have helped.